# Exercise 2.13 in Wackerly Mathematical statistics

Tags: probability

Three radar sets, operating independently, are set to detect any aircraft flying through a certain area. Each set has a probability of $0.02$ of failing to detect a plane in its area.

Exercise 2.13 asks: What is the probability that one radar will correctly detect exactly three aircrafts before it fails to detect one, if aircraft arrivals are independent single events occurring at different times.

I can do Exercise 2.13 but Suppose that I change Exercise 2.13 slightly to:

> What is the probability that the system of three radar sets will correctly detect exactly three aircrafts before it fails to detect one, if aircraft arrivals are independent single events occurring at different times?

I think I need to consider all cases: for instance the first aircraft could be detected by all three radars, second aircraft could only be detected by one radar and third aircraft could be detected by 2 radar and last aircraft not detected by any of three radars so I guess that I need to take all combinations of these but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your detection criteria for the system of the radar sets is "at least one of them detecting", then you can note that the probability that none of them detect a plane is if they each fail independently, which happens with probability ($0.02^3$); so you can effectively reduce the case to one radar with the above fail probability.

You can perhaps have more fun with this problem if your detection criteria is "at least 2/3 of them detecting", but the above should answer your question I think.

Comment: So what the final answer should be? just checking if I got it right

Comment: It is (1 - 0.02$^3$)$^3 *$ 0.02$^3$ which is 7.9998 x $10^-6$ I think