# Probability of independent events (Checking if my answer is right)

Tags: probability

Three radar sets, operating independently, are set to detect any aircraft flying through a certain area. Each set has a probability of $0.02$ of failing to detect a plane in its area.

What is the probability that the system of three radar sets will correctly detect exactly three aircrafts before it fails to detect one, if aircraft arrivals are independent single events occurring at different times?

My answer is $7.999808002\times10^{-6}$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is; I put it as a comment to my answer to your previous question. [Exercise 2.13 in Wackerly Mathematical statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724097/exercise-2-13-in-wackerly-mathematical-statistics/2724124)